# GIT: ignore everything except sub-subdirectory and some files

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm banging my head against the wall with this, I hope you people can help me...
I have this structure of files :

```
/public/images/foo
/public/images/foo/default.jpg
/public/images/foo/1/...
/public/images/foo/2/...
/public/images/bar
/public/images/bar/default.jpg
/public/images/bar/1/...
/public/images/bar/2/...
/public/images/baz
/public/images/baz/default.jpg
/public/images/baz/1/...
/public/images/baz/2/...
/public/images/other/...
```

I want to ignore everything inside `images` but keep the `default.jpg` files and the `other` folder and it's content. What I have in my .gitignore doesn't work as expected, the `default.jpg` files are still ignored :

```
/public/images/*
!/public/images/*/default.jpg
!/public/images/other/
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution with a friend :

```
/public/images/*
!/public/images/*/
/public/images/*/*
!/public/images/other/*
!/public/images/*/default.jpg
```

Here I can forget everything inside `images` but keep some folders by naming them and also keep first level `default.jpg` files.The problem was that you need to be specific when working with subdirectories whitelisting.

Answer (score 1):

`!public/images/**/default.jpg` Should have 2 stars instead of 1 to represent the current dir.

Comment: 2 stars means 0 or N folders not the current one I think. But anyway, it doesn't solves the problem the `default.jpg` are still ignored.

Answer (score -2):

If your files are already in the repository you will have to delete them and only then you will be able to "ignore" them.

#### How to remove tracked files?

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

Now you can use the `.gitignore` file.

---

If you wish to ignore specific file (in your case you want the folder itself so it suitable for your csse) you can use the `assume-unchanged` flag
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

#### --[no-]assume-unchanged

> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.
>   Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths.
>
> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

[image]